# Add Numeric list column for each row like in excel

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

[image]

How to add a column in wpf datagrid that shows a numeric list for each row like in excel?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `LoadingRow` event to your `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid LoadingRow="grd_OnLoadingRow" Name="grd" ... >
```

Then:

```
private void grd_OnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
     e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex()).ToString();
}
```

But it start counting from `0` if you want to start from `1` you can try this:

```
e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex() + 1).ToString();
```

Comment: @Arianit...Well if you want to start from `1` you can try this: `e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex() + 1).ToString();`